# selected option in select element does not work in react

Tags: reactjs-flux, reactjs

Following code in react shows this error:

"Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on ".

```
<select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

tried this but still does not work:

```
<select value="1">
        <option value="" disabled>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Trying to implement as in doc in this [link](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-select-value) but cant make the selected work inside option. Also i am looking to make "choose your option" as a default selected option when the form first loads

Answer (score 4):

You should keep a state variable in your component. I've written some code, and here is a [live JSBin](https://jsbin.com/qiliqe/edit?html,js,output):

```
var MySelect = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      value: "0"
    };
  },

  handleChange: function(event) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value, " was selected");
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="0">Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
    );
  }
})

React.render(
  <MySelect />, document.body
);
```

Replace the `console.log` with a Flux event or pass the value to your parent with a callback.